# Copying in Excel from one workbook to another and copying cells data to another workbook

Tags: excel

I need to find a specific cell on a second workbook and return its value.
I have a range that always changes, but I can filter out the bad values.
The cell i need to copy (MCN #) from one workbook to another is changing in its format.

Sometimes it is single line, sometimes its merged over 7 or so lines.The code i have that works is:

```
=HLOOKUP("MCN #",[CuPe1810_CH520.xlsx]CuPe1820_CH520!$A$1:$S$16,2,FALSE)
```

I am looking for the "MCN #" off the linked workbook, and returning the line value (B3) that I assign to it on the primary workbook.

I need to have the [CuPe1810_CH520.xlsx] change from a user input value, and I need to have the tab or range (CuPe1820_CH520!$A$1:$S$16)change to the same name minus the .xlsx so in my example the CuPe1820_CH520 would repesent a tab name AND a .xlsx name. I need help in getting this to work based on user input and can be done formulas or macros, I do not care.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

In the example below, `F1` (or `$F$1` for short code) is the cell that you are editing to update your formula.

`A1` is the cell formula that we're updating.

If you have more than one cell you need to update, you can loop through them in a `For Each` loop, or you can use the `Range("SomeRange").AutoFill Destination:=Range("SomeDestination")` function.

`Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` may need to be updated in your situation - to point to the path of the file.

This goes in your worksheet object (`Worksheet_Change` event).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$F$1" Then
    'Range to update formula goes here
    Range("A1").Formula = "='" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\[" & [F1] & ".xlsx]" & [F1] & "'!A1"
End If
End Sub
```

In the above example, you don't need to put `.xlsx` in the input string.